# html5 video "ended" event not working in chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video

I have two buttons on a page that trigger two functions that make two html5 video play, hide and show some elements (including themselves), and call another simple function on ended (that causes the video to go to the first frame and pause, for the effect to work properly).

```
$('#rotate').click(function rotate(){

$('#rotate').hide();
$('#front_view').css('z-index','2');
$('#back_view').css('z-index','3');

//this is the video:
    $('#body_animation').trigger("play").show().bind('ended', function () {
    $('#back_view').show();
    $('#front_view').fadeOut(500);
    $(this).hide();

    this.currentTime = 0;           
    this.pause();

    });

    $('#rotate_reverse').delay(2000).fadeIn(0);
});
```

This works fine in firefox and safari, but in chrome and IE something strange happens. The first time the page loads, the "ended" event doesn't seem work. It works fine if you refresh the site (or if you run it offline), though.

You can check the code in here, I narrowed all the site to this problem, so you can see it better:

http://www.hidden-workshop.com/test/

The actual videos and images are different, but the problem is the same. I'm busting my head trying to solve this thing, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your test page isn't live anymore, so I can't check this, but I found that if looping is enabled for the  tag (e.g., `<video loop="loop">`), the "ended" event wasn't firing in Chrome or IE (I didn't test in Firefox). Once I removed the loop attribute, the "ended" event fired in both browsers.

**HTML (with loop attribute, which will prevent the 'ended' event form firing):**

Remove the loop attribute if you want the 'ended' event to fire...

```
<video id="video" loop="loop">
    <source src="whatever.mp4" width="320" height="240" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support this HTML5 video tag.
</video>
```

**Javascript:**

```
//NOTE: This only fires if looping is disabled for the video!
$("#video").bind("ended", function() {
    alert('Video ended!');
});
```

Comment: ^ Note that this is jQuery and not pure Javascript

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically adding a `<video>` to your page that wasn't present in the HTML served from the server you may encounter a race condition that can result in the `ended` event not being recognized - even if it was added correctly.

I am using `knockoutjs` to add a different template for phone vs desktop.

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: videoTemplate, afterRender: initializeVideo }">
```

This dynamically creates me a `<video`> element and then calls `initializeVideo()` after the template is rendered (added to the DOM) to bind the events :

```
 $('video#flexVideo').off('ended').on('ended', (evt) =>
 {
       alert('ended fired');

 }).css('border', '2px solid yellow');   // add yellow border so we know element existed
```

On my screen the video gets a yellow border (proving the video was present in the DOM and there were no typos). However for some reason the browser isn't yet able to attach the `ended` event to it - I assume perhaps it was not initialized yet.

Chrome debugging tools shows that it is added, but it doesn't actually work!

[image]

It does this in Firefox, Chrome + IE10 which was slightly surprising.

One solution is this:

```
    $('video#flexVideo').off('loadstart').on('loadstart', (evt) =>
    {
        $('video#flexVideo').off('ended').on('ended', (evt) =>
        {
            alert('ended fired');

        }).css('border', '2px solid yellow');

    }).css('border', '2px solid orange');
```

The `loadstart` event seems to be bindable right away.

Another is perhaps just a `setTimeout` - or just bind the event on play.